# How to receive Notifications while my app isn't running?

Tags: android, push-notification

I'm working on an android app that will mirror my university's website that the employees use, and there is an option to apply for a "vacation/dismissal" (and when ever an employee uses this option his superior/manager should get a notification about it),but i'm confused on how will the manager receive a notification on his phone if for example: an employee apply for a vacation using the website and not the mobile app.

I'm new to android development and i have seen similar question to mine answered here, but the answer is 6 years old, so i want to know whats the best modern way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use Firebase Cloud Messaging, But i think in your case it won't be that simple. 
As your app is mirroring your website, so website will be having a database, which i think won't be Firebase Db. So you will have to somehow hook the database event, when an employee marks vacation, then you have to call cloud functions.

```
Cloud Functions for Firebase lets you automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features and HTTPS requests.
```

You will have to call this url, whenever you write in your database, and then from cloud functions you will have to trigger FCM.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Notification requires the device token and using [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

But in your case, Some employee is using the website to apply so you aren't able to get the device token of that devices so as per my concern this is not possible to send notification in this case.
But if Employee will use the Android mobile application to apply then you can use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) 
to send the notification.

Hope, this will help you to clear about notification.
Happy coding...

Comment: yeah but for example if u sent me a message on facebook through the web i will still get a notification on my mobile phone too!

Comment: Okay, have you installed facebook mobile app in your phone?

Comment: yes i did... oh u meant if the manager/superior didn't have the app they wont get the notification since there is no token for their devices?

Comment: oh i see, sorry for the miss understanding.. but the managers will have the app for sure.

Comment: Okay No Problem.

Comment: If My answer helped you to clear queries, can you please accept my answer?

Comment: well everyone helped me with this so i up voted everyone's answer but its kinda awkward to give only one an accepted answer . but i guess i should give it to the most beneficial one so i would probably give it to @nkalra0123 since he talked about cloud functions&DB but everyone else's answer is really really appreciated, thank you again.

Comment: Okay, No problem.

Comment: You can create a new db, with employee id as primary key and two columns, one for webtoken and one for android token, so whenever an employee marks vacation in your orig db, you have to find their managers and then with manager you have to look up in this new db to get tokens, and then you can send notification messages. This new db and sending firebase messages work you can do in cloud functions,Web token is for sending notification messages on websites, check this link for web notifications https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-add-push-notifications-to-a-web-app-with-firebase-528a702e13e1

Answer (score 0):

Here is my thought, You mention that your manager uses the mobile to get the notification of the employee vacation request. so either you get your manager phone token using firebase or you have to get token of the code using your own code and store that token in your web database. After that when employee request for the vacation from mobile or from the website then there is push generation option in the firebase so you have to integrate that code in both sides website as well as in the mobile application also.

so i think this is the solution that i thought.below is the link for push fire from web.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/

Here is the documentation for the android application integration:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: thank you for the clarification.. btw the first link doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate Firebase to your app and generate FCM Token.Save them every time the user logins. Now you can send the notification to particular users using this token.
check this link to set up Firebase and generate FCM Token:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client